# Check if object property already exist in arraylist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to verify if an object property already exists in an ArrayList.

First, I created a class for my object so it has multiple properties (for example: title, author, etc..).
Then I created an ArrayList for those objects. And is the ArrayList the best way to list an object, I heard about list(T) ?

Now, before creating another object, I want to check if one of the property already exists, for example the title.

So I wrote this code:

```
Public Class object

    Private _title as String
    Private _author as String

    Public Sub New(ByVal title as string, ByVal author as string)
        _title = title
        _author = author
    End Sub
End Class
```

````
Public Class Form1

    Dim myobject As object
    Dim objectlist As New ArrayList

    myobject = new object(title, author)

    For i as Interger = 0 To objectlist.Count - 1
        If objectlist(i).title = "Title" Then
            MsgBox("Already exist")
        Else
            objectlist.Add(object)
        End If
    Next

End Class
```
````

Comment: I don't actually see what your question is, i.e. what result did your code give and why was the result not what you were looking for?  Also, the term `object property` refers to the defined properties of the object; I presume you not are asking whether or not an object property exists because you have already defined the object properties.  Are you actually asking whether or not there is a specific data element in your objectlist? We can answer once your question is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class MyObject

    Property Title As String
    Property Author As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal title As String, ByVal author As String)
        _Title = title
        _Author = author
    End Sub
End Class


    Dim myobject As Object
    Dim objectlist As New List(Of MyObject)

    myobject = objectlist.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Title = "Title")

    If myobject Is Nothing Then
        objectlist.Add(New MyObject("NewTitle", "NewAuthor"))
    Else
        MsgBox("Already Exists!")
    End If
```